# Problem with killing newly spawned sprites

Tags: python, pygame

So I made a game that has a character that shoots zombies. The zombies spawn because of a triggered timer; so whenever the timer triggers a zombie spawns. I need the zombies to die after they get shot, I set a collision system, however, I can only shoot one the zombies and the rest don't get killed.

Here is my code...

```
import random

import pygame
from sys import exit
from random import randint
import math
from pygame.math import Vector2
from pygame.constants import K_LSHIFT, K_SPACE, MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, MOUSEBUTTONUP, K_e
pygame.init()
import time
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)




class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x , y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load('graphics/Robot 1/robot1_gun.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.orig_image = pygame.image.load('graphics/Robot 1/robot1_gun.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rotate_vel = 1
        self.cross_image = pygame.image.load('graphics/crosshair049.png')
        

    def draw(self, surface):
        """ Draw on surface """
        # blit yourself at your current position
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        dir_vec = pygame.math.Vector2()
        dir_vec.from_polar((180, -self.rotate_vel))
        cross_pos = dir_vec + self.rect.center
        cross_x, cross_y = round(cross_pos.x), round(cross_pos.y)
        surface.blit(self.cross_image,  self.cross_image.get_rect(center = (cross_x, cross_y)))
        

    def movement(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
        dist = 3 # distance moved in 1 frame, try changing it to 5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN] or key[pygame.K_s]: # down key
            self.y += dist # move down
        elif key[pygame.K_UP] or key[pygame.K_w]: # up key
            self.y -= dist # move up
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] or key[pygame.K_d]: # right key
            self.x += dist # move right
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT] or key[pygame.K_a]: # left key
            self.x -= dist # move left


    def rotate(self, surface):

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_LSHIFT]:
            self.rotate_vel += 7
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.orig_image, self.rotate_vel)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
            surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        if keys[K_SPACE]:
            self.rotate_vel += -7
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.orig_image, self.rotate_vel)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
            surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)


    def update(self):
        self.movement()
        self.draw(screen)
        self.rotate(screen)



class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, angle):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('graphics/weapons/bullets/default_bullet.png')
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)
        self.speed = 25
        self.pos = pos
        self.dir_vec = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.dir_vec.from_polar((self.speed, -angle))


    def update(self, screen):
        self.pos += self.dir_vec
        self.rect.center = round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)



class Zombie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x , y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load('graphics/zombie/zoimbie1_hold.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x,y))
        self.orig_image = pygame.image.load('graphics/Robot 1/robot1_gun.png').convert_alpha()

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.draw(screen)



#screen
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))

#player
player_sprite = Player(600, 300)
player = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
player.add(player_sprite)

#bullet
bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

XP = 0

#Zombie
zombie = pygame.sprite.Group()
zombie_limit = 5
zombie_x = random.randint(100, 1100)
zombie_y = random.randint(50, 450)
zombie_sprite = Zombie(zombie_x, zombie_y)
"""
zombie_spawn_timer
"""
zombie_spawn_timer = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(zombie_spawn_timer , 1000)

#keys
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()






running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                    pos = player_sprite.rect.center
                    new_bullet = Bullet(pos, player_sprite.rotate_vel)
                    bullet_group.add(new_bullet)

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(zombie_sprite, bullet_group, True):
                zombie_sprite.kill()

        if event.type == zombie_spawn_timer and len(zombie.sprites()) < zombie_limit:
            zombie_x = random.randint(100, 1100)
            zombie_y = random.randint(50, 450)
            zombie_sprite = Zombie(zombie_x, zombie_y)
            zombie.add(zombie_sprite)





    bullet_group.update(screen)
    #screen
    screen.fill('grey')
    #player sprite funtions
    player.update() 
    #buller group draw
    bullet_group.draw(screen)
    bullet_group.update(screen)
    #zombie update
    zombie.update()

    clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) instead of [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide):

```py
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                    pos = player_sprite.rect.center
                    new_bullet = Bullet(pos, player_sprite.rotate_vel)
                    bullet_group.add(new_bullet)

        # DELETE
        # if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(zombie_sprite, bullet_group, True):
        #        zombie_sprite.kill()

        if event.type == zombie_spawn_timer and len(zombie.sprites()) < zombie_limit:
            zombie_x = random.randint(100, 1100)
            zombie_y = random.randint(50, 450)
            zombie_sprite = Zombie(zombie_x, zombie_y)
            zombie.add(zombie_sprite)

    # INSERT
    pygame.sprite.groupcollide(zombie, bullet_group, True, True)

    # [...]
```

[`pygame.sprite.groupcollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) :

> This will find collisions between all the Sprites in two groups. [...]
>
> If either dokill argument is True, the colliding Sprites will be removed from their respective Group.